# Where to find coredump on Azure App Service using Linux?

Tags: .net-core, segmentation-fault, azure-web-app-service

I am using Azure App Service hosted on linux to use a .Net Core 6.0 app.

I have a null pointer error that is resulting in a segfault, that in turn is taking down the app service. I have had a few errors that result in segfaults so while I can fix the null pointer I really want to find why the container is crashing.

I can see the the following in **AppServiceConsoleLogs**:

> /opt/startup/startup.sh: line 17: 65 Segmentation fault (core dumped) dotnet xxx.dll

I am hoping if I can find the dumped core I might figure out the segmentation fault.

I have looked around the folders by going into the SSH console, but I cannot find anything that looks like memory dump.

Comment: We can see our source files in [site/wwwroot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gMC3.png) root directory.

Answer (score 1):

> Where to find coredump on Azure App Service using Linux?

I have deployed the .NET Core 6 App to Azure App service.

- Navigate to `Azure portal` => your `Deployed App Service` => `Advanced Tools` => `Go` .
- Click on -  `Site wwwroot`.

[image]

- Deployed files will be compiled into `dll files`.

Click on the file, you can see the content.

[image]

- We can also check the files in `Bash`.
- In `Bash`, Navigate to the Application root directory and run  `ls`.You can see the deployed files.

[image]

- In `Configuration` section => `General Settings`, check the startup command.
- It has to be

```cs
dotnet YourAppName.dll
```

- Make sure the `dll` is available in `Bash` or `SSH`.

[image]

***Update:***

We can find the core dumps in `LogFiles/core` folder.
But initially, it is disabled.
To enable it, we need to add the below command in Startup of the deployed app service.

```cs
ulimit -c unlimited
```

Thanks @[Sourabh Edake](https://medium.com/@sourabhedake/core-dumps-how-to-enable-them-73856a437711#:%7E:text=To%20enable%20dumps%2C%20we%20need%20to%20update%20soft,following%20line%20in%20%2Fetc%2Fsecurity%2Flimits.conf%20to%20update%20system%20limit) for the command.

[image]

- Restart the app. Whenever there is an exception, the core dump will be created in the mentioned `LogFiles/core` folder.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, unfortunately I think you have miss-understood the question.  The segmentation fault hints that there is a core dump. I do not know where to fine it.

Comment: Please check the update in the Answer.

Comment: Also refer this [Blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/how-to-collect-net-core-dump-on-linux-web-app/ba-p/2260713#:~:text=1%201.%20SSH%20to%20web%20app.%202%202.,to%20see%20dump%20file%20in%20the%20%22%2Fhome%2FLogFiles%22%20directory.) by YangYu.